# predict day of time series

Tags: r, time-series, predict

I am starting to use R to make predictions and I am lost in this new world.

I have this dataset (part of my dataset):

```
date                         value

2016-12-27                   85396

2016-12-28                   78573

2016-12-29                   91593

2016-12-30                  196427

2017-01-02                  430301

2017-01-03                  409319

2017-01-04                  330748
```

I want to predict for example the `value` of 2017-01-05.

I tried to build a timeseries with `xts` and use the `Arime/forecast` but the output is a line with values that i dont understand.

Is there another way to try to predict 1 day?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't provide the code to reproduce your analysis so basically no one really knows what you did or what you are looking at which is why the question is being downvoted but in the absence of that copy and paste this into R:

```
Lines <- "date value
2016-12-27 85396
2016-12-28 78573
2016-12-29 91593
2016-12-30 196427
2017-01-02 430301
2017-01-03 409319
2017-01-04 330748"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
library(forecast)
f <- forecast(DF$value)
plot(f)
```

giving a forecast of 33075.9 for the next point and the indicated 80% and 95% confidence intervals:

```
> f
   Point Forecast      Lo 80    Hi 80       Lo 95     Hi 95
 8       330755.9  182290.65 479221.1  103697.912  557813.8
 9       330755.9  120804.85 540706.9    9663.502  651848.2
10       330755.9   73623.73 587888.0  -62493.797  724005.5
11       330755.9   33847.73 627664.0 -123325.943  784837.7
12       330755.9   -1195.86 662707.6 -176920.489  838432.2
13       330755.9  -32877.82 694389.5 -225373.861  886885.6
14       330755.9  -62012.47 723524.2 -269931.461  931443.2
15       330755.9  -89130.39 750642.1 -311404.750  972916.5
16       330755.9 -114600.14 776111.9 -350357.376 1011869.1
17       330755.9 -138690.07 800201.8 -387199.732 1048711.5
```

Comment: Thanks by you response.
Your code gave us a matrix with 10 row. Why are these 10 values equals?
How do you read the columns Lo 80,    Hi 80 ,      Lo 95,     Hi 95?
i am sorry by these questions but i am having some problems to understand this logic.

Comment: Google *confidence intervals*.   There is a vignette that comes with the forecast package that explains it further.  `help(package = forecast)` and click on User Guides.